# How to implement an OSGI dynamic metatype?

Tags: java, xml, osgi, metatype

I would customize the **OSGI-INF metatype** (xml) in order to add attributes **dynamically**.

This is an example of a metatype input:

```
<AD id="Device-Operation"
      name="Device-Operation"
      type="String"
      cardinality="0" 
      required="false"
      default="NONE" 
      description="Operations"> 

     <Option label="None" value="NONE"/>  
     <Option label="Test" value="Test"/>     
     <Option label="OtherTest" value="OtherTest"/>     
</AD>
```

I need to build these select options **dynamically**.

Have I to create a service?

And how can I update these properties from the bundle?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You can register a [MetatypeProvider](https://osgi.org/javadoc/r6/cmpn/org/osgi/service/metatype/MetaTypeProvider.html) OSGi service programmatically instead of declaring the metatype information in an XML file. By doing that, you can change re-register the service with new return values later.

Comment: Thank you very much for the helpful answer. Do you know any tutorial / example about it?

Comment: I suggest that simply check the javadoc of the interface. It has the same structure as the XML. If you know how to register an OSGi service, you know everything. You can also search for the word "MetatypeProvider" in the OSGi compendium specification.